# savePlot() error message in R: can only copy from 'windows' devices

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

Using RStudio on a Windows 8 System gives me the following error message:

```
Error in savePlot(filename = "123", type = c("png"), device = dev.cur()) : 
  can only copy from 'windows' devices
```

If I write `windows()` in the line before savePlot, the error message disappears but the plot is "empty".
The problem does not exist if I use R instead of RStudio.

Is there any other solution than "not using RStudio"?
Best regards

Edit: 
Here is more of the original code:

```
#--------------create plot

x <- df$Year
y <- df$Index1970
par(family="serif", font=1, cex=1) 
xrange <- range(x, na.rm=TRUE) 
yrange <- range(y, na.rm=TRUE) 
plot(xrange, yrange, type="n", xlab="Year",
    ylab="Price index, 1970=100" )
lines(x, y, col="black", lwd=3)
title("Belgium Property Prices from 1970-2013")
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted",
     lwd = par("lwd"), equilogs = TRUE)
savePlot(filename="D:/...RPlots/Belgium_Prices_from_1970-2013",
         type=c("wmf"),     
         device=dev.cur(), #type=c("wmf", "png", "jpeg", "jpg", "bmp", "ps", "pdf")
         restoreConsole = TRUE)
```

Where and how can I use the png, respectively the win.metafile function here?
It works in R, but not in RStudio...

Comment: use `windows()` before your plotting command.

Comment: did you add `dev.off()` after you saved the plot?

Comment: Neither `windows()`, nor `dev.off()` is helping here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `png` function. For example:

```
png(filename = "testPlot.png", width = 480, height = 480)
plot(1:10, type = 'l')
dev.off()
```

In `filename` you should define the path to the plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you post an example for the function win.metafile(). I am getting an error message there.

Comment: `Error in savePlot(filename = "D:/.../RPlots/Belgium_Prices_from_1970-2013",  : 
  can only copy from 'windows' devices`

Where should/could I use the png function to create my plot? My plot code is more than one line and if I use the png (or win.metafile) function before the line plot, the resulting image file is empty.

Comment: The reason is that you don't need use the  savePlot function. All that you nedd in this code. png  opens a file, plot creates some plot, dev.off closes the file.

Answer (score 1):

When I use RStudio, my first plot has a "RStudio" type instead "windows" type. Next plots has correct "window" type.
So i call this function (see below) before my first "saveplot", and it work's...

```
#
# Initialise les fenêtres pour RStudio
# La première fenêtre créée n'est pas toujours du type "windows", il faut en recréer une
#
init_fenetres <- function() 
{
  dev.new()
  numFenetre = dev.cur()
  mx = as.matrix(dev.cur())
  if (rownames(mx)[1] != "windows") {
    dev.new()
    numFenetre = dev.cur()
  }
  dev.off( numFenetre )
}
```